# Laravel 8: Is there a way access bound instance via and identifier? And what's the correct way for object caching?

Tags: laravel, caching, binding

I am new to Laravel.

My goal is to essentially cache some service class instances into Laravel container and retrieve them when needed. In particular, I want to cache two instances of the same class twice and identify them using string identifiers.

When I bind an instance to the container using app()->bind function, it seems the identifier has to be the class name so essentially there is no way for me to distinguish between them.

Here is a pseudocode of what I want to do when retrieving the service

```
class FooHelper {
   function getBarService($serviceClassName, $isMasterDb) {
      $name = $serviceClassName;
      if ($isMasterDb) {
         $name .= 'Master';
      } else {
         $name .= 'Slave';
      }
      if(!bound($name)) {
         $service = new ServiceClass();
         app()->bind($name, $service);
      } else {
         return app($name);
      }
   }
}
```

I am not even sure is it correct to cache service instances using the container system.

If anyone knows the correct way to achieve the above feature please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as how you envisage conditionally determining which instance to return from the service container? Any code you have, even psuedo, would be helpful.

Comment: @Peppermintology I have included a pseudocode in my post. I tried various thing such as "[ClassName => $name]" but did not work. Please help me.

Comment: Since you're binding a ready instance I think you need to use `app()->instance($name, $service)`. You can then get the instance back by using the name you bound it with

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you so much, it worked! Never thought it was so easy. I will accept if you post an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information on the application container can be found in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container)
but the short story is:

Use `bind` or `singleton` to bind a callback that constructs and instance or to bind an interface to a class that implements it. The difference between the two is that `singleton` will cache the instance it created the first time it creates it.

If you already have the instance you want to "cache" in the container then you would use `instance` so your code would become:

```
class FooHelper {
   function getBarService($serviceClassName, $isMasterDb) {
      $name = $serviceClassName;
      if ($isMasterDb) {
         $name .= 'Master';
      } else {
         $name .= 'Slave';
      }
      if(!bound($name)) {
         $service = new ServiceClass();
         app()->instance($name, $service);
      } else {
         return app($name);
      }
   }
}
```